# MySQL Error Message "#1064 - You have an error..."

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm using MySQL 5.6.33.

My table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  a1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  a2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Executing an `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO test ('a1', 'a2') VALUES ('hello', 'world');
```

throws the ugly error message

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a1', 'a2') VALUES('hello', 'world')' at line 1`

I tried modifying the AUTO_INCREMENT, incluing the primary key as in

```
INSERT INTO test ('id', 'a1', 'a2') VALUES (NULL,'hello', 'world');
```

But nothing works. Allways the same error.

I could not find any answer on SO that could resolve this. How to proceed?

Comment: because you wrote ugly script.

Comment: Ups, how does this relate to an answer? Why is my script ugly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not suppose to use `'` single-quote in with column name

```
INSERT INTO test ('a1', 'a2') VALUES ('hello', 'world');
```

instead

```
INSERT INTO test (a1, a2) VALUES ('hello', 'world');
```

Comment: @Ravi, you ROCK. How to become good in MySQL, I am following your posts for few days and very impressed from you :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 haha.. it's very basic. ;)

Comment: @Ravi, may be basic but how could I start learning it. One way is following your post, how about other way :) Any help is greatly appreciated sir.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 You just spent some time here and select `mysql` tag and go through the question and try answering them (google it). And of course, bookmark https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/

Comment: Cool, sure. Will try to follow it. Thanks a TON.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 all the best. ;)